# Hide the same div and show it when loaded

Tags: jquery, hide, show

I saw many posts about this, but what I'm looking is something more specific.

When I apply this code @ localhost works 100%, but when I test it from a host, it blinks at the same speed, but keeps showing the previous div content while takes 1 second to change its content.

This is the issue I'm talking about:

***edit**: sorry, link not available*.

And this is the code I've used:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#inicio').children().addClass('selected');

$('#inicio').on('click', function(){
    $('nav ul a').find('.selected').each( function(){
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
    });
    $('article').load('inicio.html').hide().fadeIn();
    $(this).children().addClass('selected');
});

$('#consultar_pedido').on('click', function(){
    $('nav ul a').find('.selected').each( function(){
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
    });
    $('article').load('consultapedidos.php').hide().fadeIn();
    $(this).children().addClass('selected');
});
$('#acerca_de').on('click', function(){
    $('nav ul a').find('.selected').each( function(){
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
    });
    $('article').load('acerca.html').hide().fadeIn();
    $(this).children().addClass('selected');
});
$('#contactarse').on('click', function(){
    $('nav ul a').find('.selected').each( function(){
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
    });
$('article').load('contacto.html').hide().fadeIn();
    $(this).children().addClass('selected');
});
});
```

Comment: It's most likely an issue in async, you're adding class before it can finish loading. Maybe you can use load's callback?

Comment: With `$(document).ready(function(){` it should work when the document is ready. Thanks!

Comment: I uploaded the code and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're adding class before it can finish loading. Try to use load()'s callback and see if it fixes the problem. Something like this:

```
$('#acerca_de').on('click', function(){
    var that = this;
    $('article').hide();
    $('nav ul a').find('.selected').each( function(){
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
    });
    $('article').load('acerca.html', function(){
       $(that).children().addClass('selected');
       $(this).fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Comment: you probably want to `hide()` it before the load, and `fadeIn()` in the callback, like `$('article').hide().load('acerca.html', function(){ $(that).children().addClass('selected'); $(this).fadeIn();
    });`  but yah, +1

Comment: When I read `var that = this;`... Wow never thought that way!

Answer (score 0):

first, on every `#` click you have to Hide the Div as the First Statement and then Clear the `Class` styles

```
$('#contactarse').on('click', function() 
{
    $('article').hide(); // Hide it First....
    $('nav ul a').find('.selected').each( function()
    {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
    });
    $(this).children().addClass('selected');
    $('article').load('contacto.html', function() 
    {
        $(this).fadeIn();
    }
});
```